# Ruby array of strings: split into smallest pieces

Tags: ruby

I would like to know if there is a method in Ruby that splits an `Array` of `String` in smallest pieces. Consider:

`['Cheese crayon', 'horse', 'elephant a b c']`

Is there a method that turns this into:

`['Cheese', 'crayon', 'horse', 'elephant', 'a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: Are pieces always separated by a space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
p ['Cheese crayon', 'horse', 'elephant a b c'].flat_map(&:split)
# => ["Cheese", "crayon", "horse", "elephant", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 4):

None that I know of. But you can split each string individually and then flatten the results into a single array:

```
p ['Cheese crayon', 'horse', 'elephant a b c'].map(&:split).flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
array.map { |s| s.split(/\s+/) }.flatten
```

This splits your string by any number of whitespace characters. As far as I know, it's the default behavior of `split` without any arguments, so you can shorten it to:

```
array.map(&:split).flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

```
['Cheese crayon', 'horse', 'elephant a b c'].join(' ').split
# => ["Cheese", "crayon", "horse", "elephant", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Admirable lateral thinking!